# Is data actually transferred between disk and memory when CPU first touches a anonymous file ( CSAPP)

Tags: linux, computer-science, virtual-memory

In CSAPP 2nd, Chapter 9, section 8 (in page 807)

> Anonymous file: An area can also be mapped to an anonymous file,
>   created by the kernel, that contains all binary zeros. The first time
>   the CPU touches a virtual page in such an area, the kernel finds an
>   appropriate victim page in physical memory, swaps out the victim page
>   if it is dirty, overwrites the victim page with binary zeros, and
>   updates the page table to mark the page as resident. Notice that no
>   data is actually transferred between disk and memory. For this reason,
>   pages in areas that are mapped to anonymous files are sometimes called
>   demand-zero pages.

When the victim page is dirty.I think it should be wrote back to disk.Why " Notice that no data is actually transferred between disk and memory."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is bad terminology on the part of Unix. Part of the problem is the historical lack of a hard file system (corrected in some Unix variants). In an idealized model of paging, user-created files can serve as page files. The static data (including code) can be paged directly from the executable file. The read/write data is paged from the page file. In that sense, the mapping is anonymous as there really is not a file but rather portion of a page file.

In most Unix variants, there is no page FILE but rather a swap partition. This is due poor design of the original Unix file system that has lived on for decades. The traditional Unix file system does not have the concept of a contiguous file. This makes it impossible to do logical I/O to a page file. Therefore, traditional Unix uses a swap partition instead.

Even if you map to a named file, on many Unix variations that mapping is only for the first READ. In the case of an anonymous mapping, the first read creates a demand zero page. To write it back to disk is goes to the swap partition on both cases. From the Unix perspective, calling this an "anonymous" mapping kind of makes sense but from the conceptual point of view (where one expects a memory to file mapping to be two-way) it makes no sense at all.